# How to install VS6, SP5, and Proc Pack on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-7

Need to get Visual Studio 6 Processor Pack installed on Windows 7 (32 bit).

First i installed VS6 + SP6, which prevents the PP from installing. I uninstalled VS6 and re-installed VS6 and am trying to install SP5.

It is now complaining that MDAC 2.5 or 2.6 needs to be installed first. I've tried 2.5, 2.6, and 2.8. All run through the little extract progress dialog and appear to finish. But SP5 still fails with this:

[image]

Any ideas on getting VS6 + SP5 + PP installed correctly?

EDIT: Alternatively, any way to get VS6 (or just VC6) + SP6 + PP installed correctly? Processor Pack refuses to install on SP6, insisting on SP5.

EDIT: I found a [**KB article suggesting a registry change**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/872907), and that got SP6 + PP installed, but i'm getting this error, which is apparently indicates that PP isn't installed:

```
--------------------Configuration: test - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
test.cpp
c:\svn\test\test.cpp(127) : error C2520: conversion from unsigned __int64
  to double not implemented, use signed __int64
Error executing cl.exe.

test.dll - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

EDIT: Fixed title.

Comment: Don't you have an old XP machine laying around somewhere?  Virtual PC would be another solution.  Ask questions at superuser.com

Comment: I'd argue that this is a development question, that is more likely to be encountered and solved by programmers than by "users," super or otherwise.

Comment: VPC might work, but i want to avoid that unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Though this isn't supported and you get the normal warnings about maybe not working on Windows 7, but i now have it installed and compiling.

Found a [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/cd740951-dd2c-46eb-856f-6e653a2e3d07/) to this that actually works well. Essentially you have to hand edit the STF file for VS6 Service Pack 5 to skip the MDAC check.

1. Install VS6. Do a custom install and deselect Visual Studio Analyzer, along with anything else you don't need. I ended up installing InterDev and VC++ with some misc. tools. (OLE Viewer caused problems.)
2. Extract (or copy from CD) Service Pack 5 files to a folder.
3. Modify SP598ENT.STF to remove 36 (the MDAC check) from the list in step 13

   ```
   13  Group 28 36 38 29 30 32 26 27 14 25 16 17 20 18 19 15 39 21 22 24 23 43
   ```

   and save the file. For completeness, you can possibly remove step 36 (and 37) entirely, but this has worked for me once but not the second time i tried this. Those lines are as follows:

   ```
   36  Depend "27 ? : 37"
   37  IsWin95 CustomAction "sp598ent.dll,CheckForMDAC"
   ```
4. Run SETUPSP5.EXE and let Service Pack 5 finish installing.
5. Install Processor Pack normally.

Answer (score 2):

MDAC is supposedly part of the OS in Windows 7 - see input from Microsoft moderator [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/7c20296f-6184-4c02-a616-2c6bd0bba3c9).  You may be out of luck, since Visual Studio v6 is no longer a supported product - it expired before Win7 shipped iirc.

> You cannot install MDAC 2.8 on Windows
>   7.  It is an operating system component and is shipped with Windows
>   7. Because it is already installed as part of the core OS, it is not "downgradable".

Comment: Agreed. I ran into this a few months ago, and went with virtualization to solve.

Comment: @Mark - thanks, there's nothing like real-world experience in these cases

Answer (score -1):

On the some old XP machine you may make DLL wrapper about MDACxxx (or any dll, tlb) who you want.
Make installation on the XP (make sure that path of orginal DLL to be in AppPath not WinSysPath) and install on your Win7 and at the end include your DLL in your install procedure.